# How to use image from PIL ImageGrab without saving it to a file?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to compare the structural similarity of two images with the skimage package but it only works if use two images saved on my pc and not when I use an image created by ImageGrab from PIL even it's basically the same image.

```
def structural_sim(img1, img2):
    sim, diff = structural_similarity(img1, img2, full=True)
    return sim

#doesn't work
tempScreen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(985,193,1895,704))

sim = structural_sim(tempScreen, cv2.imread('08-55-48.PNG', 0))

#works
tempScreen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(985,193,1895,704))
tempScreen.save("temp.PNG")

sim = structural_sim(cv2.imread('temp.PNG', 0), cv2.imread('08-55-48.PNG', 0))
```

The error is the following

> AttributeError: shape. Did you mean: 'save'?

How can I correctly use the result of `ImageGrab.grab` without using `.save` and then `cv2.imread`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question confuses me, but I think you want to get a Numpy array, like you would from `cv2.imread()` so that you can use it with `scikit-image`. But you currently have a `PIL Image` instead.

So, to get a Numpy array from a `PIL Image`, you need:

```
import numpy as np

na = np.array(YOUR_GRABBED_PILIMAGE)
```

Comment: It's an easy duplicate